# htaccess file-exist check doesnt seem to work when used with apache Alias's

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been using .htaccess files for 15 years so I feel reasonably confident with them. But today I discovered that the "file exists" check doesn't seem to work correctly with Apache's Alias command - and I can't figure out why not (I've read the docs multiple times and can't find anything that would explain this specifically).

e.g. this simple http conf:

```
Alias /site             /sites/site1.com
```

e.g. with this simple htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/

# this never matches: (despite being used in most examples all over the web)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.extension -f
# this doesn't match either: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f

RewriteRule (.*)$ FailOnPurpose [NC]
</IfModule>
```

...never triggers. The intent here was:

1. When a request comes in...
2. ... check if there is a file with that name and the extension "extension"
3. ... if so: rewrite

e.g. if I request:

```
http://example.com/site/a.png
```

and there's a file:

```
/sites/site.com/a.png.extension
```

then I expected the RewriteCond to work.

If I remove all aliases from apache, and use plain direct subfolders, then it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `DOCUMENT_ROOT` inside context of alias directory because `DOCUMENT_ROOT` will point to a path outside alias path and your condition will always fail.

You may use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.extension -f
RewriteRule (.*) FailOnPurpose [L,QSA]
```

I have tested it on my local Apache 2.4 within an alias .htaccess